# Jquery .val always return same value for dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The below is my code for an ajax multiple image upload

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var settings = {
        url: "upload.php",
        method: "POST",
        allowedTypes:"jpg,png",
        fileName: "myfile",
        formData: {"projectId":$('#project_name').val()},
        multiple: true,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
        {
            $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
        },
        afterUploadAll:function()
        {
            alert("all images uploaded!!");
        },
        onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
        {       
            $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
        }
    }
    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

});
</script>
```

Below is my textfield value

```
<select class="form-control" name="project_name" id="project_name">
<option value="1">Project 1</option>
<option value="2">Project 2</option>                                    
</select>
```

Below is my file uploader div

```
<div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>
```

The div above use a js file that can ajax upload several images at a go to a folder, its work. but when i try to send data(selected dropdown value), its always at 1 despite I use jquery to initiate.

Could there be something wrong at the document.ready portion.

Thanks

When I change the value of the dropdown, and use the image upload, the project id is always **1** , despite i change the value of the dropdown and try get the value with

```
$('#project_name').val()
```

How do I change my code so when the script to upload image is execute, it will get the current selected dropdown by the id project_name, selected.val

**Thanks!**

Comment: You are trying to get value of `select` on document ready handler, at that point your select will always be at default value(First One). You need to get value of your `select`  on its change handler instead of document ready handler.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('#project_name option:selected').val()
```

which gets the *selected option's value*

Now if you want to get option text i.e. Project 1, Project 2 etc., you need to write

```
$('#project_name option:selected').text()
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is actually with your code set-up. You have created your `settings` inside `$(document).ready`. So even though if you change `selected option` it will not change value inside `settings` defined during `document ready`. You need to update your settings `onchange` or in some other way.

Comment: it seems that my code only initiate once and its fixed at 1, on load. and it won't re-trigger again to get the selected val. maybe I need destroy "setting" and retrigger when option change

Answer (score 3):

Bind the upload to the submit of the form

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
    var settings = {
        url: "upload.php",
        method: "POST",
        allowedTypes:"jpg,png",
        fileName: "myfile",
        formData: {"projectId":$('#project_name option:selected').val()},
        multiple: true,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
        {
            $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
        },
        afterUploadAll:function()
        {
            alert("all images uploaded!!");
        },
        onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
        {       
            $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
        }
    }
    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

});
});
```

Comment: There is no "submit" button in this case, its just select a dropdownlist and an ajax javascript.

Comment: how do you upload the files if you have no subimt button?

Answer (score 1):

try `$("#project_name option:selected").val();`